# 'use of deleted function' when merging two vectors of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, unique-ptr, deleted-functions

I'm trying to merge two vectors of `unique_ptr` (i.e. `std::move` them out from one and into another) and I keep running into a "use of deleted function..." wall of error text. According to the error, I am apparently trying to use `unique_ptr`'s deleted copy constructor, but I'm not sure why. Below is the code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

struct Foo {
    int f;

    Foo(int f) : f(f) {}
};

struct Wrapper {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> foos;

    void add(std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo) {
        foos.push_back(std::move(foo));
    }

    void add_all(const Wrapper& other) {
        foos.reserve(foos.size() + other.foos.size());

        // This is the offending line
        std::move(other.foos.begin(), 
                  other.foos.end(), 
                  std::back_inserter(foos));
    }
};

int main() {
    Wrapper w1;
    Wrapper w2;

    std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo1(new Foo(1));
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo2(new Foo(2));

    w1.add(std::move(foo1));
    w2.add(std::move(foo2));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to move from a constant `Wrapper` object. Generally move semantics also require the object you are moving away from to be mutable (i.e. not `const`). In your code the type of the `other` parameter in the `add_all` method is `const Wrapper&`, therefore `other.foos` also refers to a constant vector, and you can't move away from it.

Change the type of the `other` parameter to `Wrapper&` to make it work.

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have done it! I suppose mutability for move semantics makes sense, since other's vector will be rendered invalid as a result.

Comment: @AUD_FOR_IUV Welcome to Stack Overflow! :-)